# How to map through an array of input files?

Tags: javascript, file

I have two functions: one that turn files into dataUrl and another that returns a promise with the result:

```
fileToDataURL(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader()
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    reader.onload = function (event) {
      resolve(event.target.result)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  })
}  

getDataURLs (target) {
  // target => <input type="file" id="file">      
  return Promise.all(target.files.map(fileToDataURL))
}
```

target.files.map returns: `TypeError: target.files.map is not a function`. H

How to modify `getDataUrls` so it returns an array with the dataUrls?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
function getDataURLs(target) {
  // target => <input type="file" id="file">      
  return Promise.all([...target.files].map(fileToDataURL))
}
```

[`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) is not an `Array`, and does not inherit from `Array`, but it does implement [the iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), so you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get it as an array.

In case you're wondering how to check if a class like `FileList` supports the spread syntax, you can do this:

```js
console.log(FileList.prototype[Symbol.iterator]);
```

If that returns a function (which it does), then that returned function is a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) that is invoked on an instance of the class by the spread syntax.

Comment: Well I've provided links on things that may be unclear. Hopefully following them should clarify everything I'm covering.

Comment: Why did you use `Promise.all` in your example? Why not using just `[...target.files].map` ? Is there any benefits using promises over array?

Comment: @MohamedAbdallah `Promise.all()` takes an iterable of promises and returns a single promise which resolves to an array. Read the question, `Promise.all()` is used there as well, it's not just in my answer. FYI [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is extremely trivial to google.

Comment: My question wasn't what is `Promise.all()`, it was what the benefit for that case over normal array. BTW thank you, your answer saved my day.

Answer (score 5):

While Patrick Roberts' answer is true, you may face an issue on TypeScript:

[image: issue screenshot]

> Type 'FileList' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators. ts(2569)

You can find a complete answer about `--downlevelIteration` the post [Why `downlevelIteration` is not on by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69046124/1248177).

In our case, to iterate on a `FileList`, instead of the spread operator, use `Array.from()`:

```
function getDataURLs(target) {
  // target => <input type="file" id="file">      
  return Promise.all(Array.from(target.files).map(fileToDataURL))
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in the code - it has an extra `]` character.  It should be:
`return Promise.all(Array.from(target.files).map(fileToDataURL))`