# How can I do [...arguments].map in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm pretty sure that `[...arguments].map(x => someFunc(x))` works fine in Javascript, but when I try it in Typescript I get the following error:

> Type `IArguments` is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option `--downlevelIteration` to allow iterating of iterators.

Does anyone have a clue what is the issue here, and how can I resolve it without changing compiler configuration?

### Update

I am able to solve it with `Array.from(arguments).map(x => someFunc(x))`, but would still be happy to know why the spread operator (`...`) is not working here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why \`downlevelIteration\` is not on by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441292/why-downleveliteration-is-not-on-by-default)

Comment: @user1538301: I have no idea what this type is myself, this error just popped up as I used `arguments`, which is a valid expression in Javascript.

Comment: @MatSz: No, it doesn't. My question is why can I not use the spread operator here.

Comment: [It works fine for me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKRBvAsAKEUQG0A6cgQwCcBzEAWwFMwoBnAXVPooAc0APRAF4AfIn4YCAXyA) so you should work on producing a [mcve], possibly with compiler options, etc

Comment: @goodvibration: it answers why the spread operator is disabled for non-arrays by default.

Comment: @MatSz: I take it back. It does pretty much answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to turn on `downlevelIteration`.The reason why typescript doesn't know `IArguments` is that you didn't add `es6.iterator` or `esnext` to `compilerOptions.lib`