# How to iterate through a map in Typescript: for...in? for...of? forEach?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to understand the syntax for iterating through a map in Typescript.  The keys in my map are strings.  The values are arrays of strings.

Here is some sample code:

```
let attributeMap: Map<string, string[]> = new Map<string, string[]>();

// sample data
let sampleKey1 = "bob";

// populate map
let value: string[] = attributeMap.get(sampleKey1) || [];
value.push("clever");
attributeMap.set(sampleKey1, value);

value = attributeMap.get(sampleKey1) || [];
value.push("funny");
attributeMap.set(sampleKey1, value);


// try looping through the map
for (let key in attributeMap) {
    console.log(attributeMap.get(key));
    console.log("WE'RE IN THE MAP!");
}

console.log("done");
```

When I run this code, the only thing printed is "done".

Why is it that nothing in the map gets printed, nor does the message "WE'RE IN THE MAP"?   It's as if the for loop is never entered.  Why is that and how would I fix that?

Comment: The answer is that you shouldn't use `for..in` to iterate a map. A counter question would be why would you want to do that, instead of using a conventional approach?

Comment: When you say conventional approach, what do you mean?  I also tried using forEach and got the same result.

Comment: `Map#forEach` or `for..of`, for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you set keys to Maps, the keys do not get put onto the Map instance - they're stored *internally* in the Map, and can only be accessed by using one of the various Map iteration methods. `for..in` only iterates over properties *directly on* an object or its prototypes.

To iterate over the Map, try something like this instead:

```
for (const [key, value] of attributeMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

`for..in` makes sense when your collection is a *normal object* with key-value pairs on the object itself, but not for Maps, which stores data differently.

When a property is directly on an object, the syntax will usually look something like this:

```
someObj.someProp = 'someVal';
```

This puts the `someProp` property onto the `someObj` object.

But Maps store their data inside the [[MapData]] [internal slot](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-map.prototype.set) of the Map, and not directly on different properties of the Map.

Just as a theoretical exercise, in JS, you *could* put a property directly on a Map instance and it'll be iterated over with `for..in` (basically, abusing a map as an object with own-properties):

```
const map = new Map();
map.foo = 'bar';
for (const prop in map) {
  // ...
}
```

But that's quite an antipattern and should never be done. Either use an object and set/retrieve properties with dot and bracket notation (and other object methods like `Object.entries`), or use a Map and set/retrieve properties with `Map.get` and `Map.set` and the other Map methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot - what is the difference between being "put onto the Map instance" vs "being stored *internally* in the Map"?

Comment: Thanks for your added clarification.  That makes sense.  However, when I try the technique you recommended, I get the following error: `Type 'IterableIterator<[string, string[]]>' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.`. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Iterators are great. If you want to write source code with modern syntax (which you should!), I'd suggest just turning on `downlevelIteration`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441292/why-downleveliteration-is-not-on-by-default. Map iteration uses iterators, not arrays, so you'll probably want `downlevelIteration` regardless.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  So, one more follow up.  Why would forEach not work in this case?  When I do the following code, I get the same result as when I did the `for...in` code in the initial question.  
`Object.keys(map).forEach(key => {
    console.log(map.get(key));
    console.log("WE'RE IN THE MAP!");
});`

Comment: `Object.keys` uses very similar logic to `for..in` - it only iterates over properties *directly on the object*. But Map properties aren't stored on the map instance, but inside the `MapData` slot (which is not directly exposed to the JS, except through the Map-specific iteration methods).

Comment: Thank you very much!!  So, do you have any opinion about someone doing `let keys = Array.from(attributeMap.keys());` and then iterating through the keys as an array instead?

Comment: Sure, that's just fine if you're happy with the way that code looks. It's not as concise as I'd personally prefer, but there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Got it.  So your top preference would be to turn on `downlevelIteration` and use Iterators to their full capacity.  The `Array.from()` solution gets the job done but is not as elegant/concise.  Your comments are very helpful.