# Type 'IterableIterator<number>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, slider

I'm trying to evolve with this Slider, but I get the following error when using TypeScript React in this Next.js project:

"Type 'IterableIterator' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher."

The code is this:

```
import { useKeenSlider } from 'keen-slider/react'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import 'keen-slider/keen-slider.min.css'
import './styles.css'

export default function Slider() {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0)
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
  const [sliderRef, instanceRef] = useKeenSlider({
    initial: 0,
    slideChanged(slider) {
      setCurrentSlide(slider.track.details.rel)
    },
    created() {
      setLoaded(true)
    }
  })

  return (
    <>
      <div className="navigation-wrapper">
        <div ref={sliderRef} className="keen-slider">
          <div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide1">1</div>
          <div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide2">2</div>
          <div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide3">3</div>
          <div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide4">4</div>
          <div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide5">5</div>
          <div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide6">6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {loaded && instanceRef.current && (
        <div className="dots">
          {[
            ...Array(instanceRef.current.track.details.slides.length).keys()
          ].map(idx => {
            return (
              <button
                key={idx}
                onClick={() => {
                  instanceRef.current?.moveToIdx(idx)
                }}
                className={'dot' + (currentSlide === idx ? ' active' : '')}
              ></button>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

I followed the Keen Slider documentation, but the example was in JavaScript. Because I'm using TypeScript, I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: You are transpiling into a target version of JavaScript which does not support iterating over `IterableIterator`. Go into your tsconfig.json and either change target to `"target": "es2015"` or set `"downlevelIteration": true`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

TypeScript code is transpiled to JavaScript. TypeScript developers have to make a decision which version of JavaScript they want to target. Choosing a lower version means that the code can be executed in older browsers, ultimately reaching a larger user base. Developers can still use modern JavaScript features, as long as these features can be *downleveled* to older JavaScript versions.

Most modern JavaScript features can be emulated in lower versions, but we have to be explicit when dealing with `IterableIterator`. If you want to write code that depends on `IterableIterator`, you have to either increase your `target` version or set `downlevelIteration` to `true`.

*tsconfig.json*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015"
    // or
    "downlevelIteration": true
  }
}
```

---

Further resources:

- [Why is `downlevelIteration` not on by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441292/why-downleveliteration-is-not-on-by-default)

Comment: I got this error when attempting to use the spread operator on a JS Map() inside a TypeScript project.  I added the es2015 target (it was previously set to es5) in my tsconfig.json and it fixed the problem.  Thanks

Comment: For some reason I still intermittently get this error even after setting `downlevelIteration: true`. Our target is es5.

Comment: I was getting this error despite having all targets set to either `ES2015` or `ES6`. `ES6` is supposed to be equivalent to `ES2015` according to every site I read, but the error didn't go away until I changed everything to `ES2015`.

Comment: You have to delete .next folder and then build for the changes to apply, as @cglacet pointed below.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, I added a target option as already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74266946/1720199):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6"
  }
}
```

But I also had to reset my Nextjs cache before `next build` worked as expected:

```bash
# next build doesn't work
rm -rf .next 
# next build works
```

Answer (score 0):

The slide object has an attribute called abs that serves as the index, so you can change the way you map it

before:

```
{loaded && instanceRef.current && (
    <div className="dots">
      {[
        ...Array(instanceRef.current.track.details.slides.length).keys()
      ].map(idx => {
        return (
          <button
            key={idx}
            onClick={() => {
              instanceRef.current?.moveToIdx(idx)
            }}
            className={'dot' + (currentSlide === idx ? ' active' : '')}
          ></button>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )}
```

after:

```
{loaded && instanceRef.current && (
    <div className="dots">
      {instanceRef.current.track.details.slides.map((slide) => {
        return (
          <button
            key={slide.abs}
            onClick={() => {
              instanceRef.current?.moveToIdx(slide.abs);
            }}
            className={
              "dot" + (currentSlide === slide.abs ? " active" : "")
            }
          ></button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  )}
```