# Next.js Type error: Type 'Set<any>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am getting the following error when compiling my Next.js app (with Typescript) with the "npm run build" command.

> Type error: Type 'Set' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher.

In my tsconfig.json file, I tried changing the target value from "es5" to "es6", "es2015", and "es2022". I still got the same error. I even tried adding the "downlevelIteration":true property, as suggested in the accepted answer from the thread below. However, I am still getting the same error.

What can I do to get rid of the error?

[Type 'IterableIterator<number>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74246843/type-iterableiteratornumber-can-only-be-iterated-through-when-using-the-d)